# printer's paper is empty check in wpf

Tags: wpf, printing

i am developing a application in wpf in which click event of the print, directly print the grid without print dialogbox.

my problem is

1) how can we check that printer has no paper means how can we recognize that printer has no paper in WPF?

2) if the page is Jam then how can i know there is error in printing the page?

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.

**PrintQueueStatus**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueuestatus.aspx

**PrintQueue**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue.aspx